# How does lasers emit photons of constant phase and frequency

Tags: coherence

In my alevel physics book it says that the  electrond in the atoms of the laser get excited and de-excited releasing photons of constant frequency.  How is this possible if the photons have energy equal to the difference in energy levels?Since the difference in energy levels are not constant then photons emitted should have a range of specific energies and therefore the photons must have different frequencies . Yet this contradicts the definition of coherence which is a property due to the waves emitted having constant frequency?[image]

Comment: Why is the difference in the energy levels not constant? What is producing the variation?

Comment: In the laser active material, there's achieved [population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion), suppose most atoms are at first exited level $n_1$, then when input photon- closely related to atom energy band goes by,- it nocks out an atom forcing it to emit a duplicated second photon. Now two same frequency photons are traveling. Then process repeats in an exponential fashion (avalanche way), producing laser beam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the photons that coming out from the laser is due to a process called **stimulated emission**, you are right that all the photons doesn't have excatly the same frequency, this is called **Broadening**, there are many types of broadenings but dont get confused, those differences in frequecies doesn't mean the photons have completely different frequencies. It just means that the frequency (or energy) of the photons will distribute around the theoretical value of the frequency. Usually the distributions profiles are lorentzians and gaussians.